# iAd ADBannerView using Auto Layout has multiple appearances

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, iad

I am trying to add an `ADBannerView` to my application.

When there is no ad to show my label is visible because the `ADBannerView` is set to be hidden:

[image]

Then when the `ADBannerView` does load it SHOULD look like this:

[image]

Except sometimes the first time you load the app, and some other times in which I haven't found any regularity yet, the `ADBannerView` appears like this:

[image]

All the content above the `ADBannerView` is pushed upwards.

My question is, is there any way to control the way the `ADBannerView` behaves? Either way it does now is fine to me, as long as I know for sure that this is the way it is going to be viewed everytime.

The constraints are rather simple:

`adBanner`:
- bottom 0
- left 0
- right 0
- height 50

`label`:
- same as `adBanner`

`start button`:
- bottom 60
- left, right 10
- height 30

Comment: It sounds like you're creating two `ADBannerViews`. One programmatically, and one with `canDisplayBannerAds = true`. Edit your question to include any relevant code.

Comment: Is that really a thing? I followed a tutorial on how to add an ad banner. It included both the iAdBannerView and the code 'canDisplayBannerAds = true'.. I will try this as soon as possible, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided I'm assuming you've created an `ADBannerView` both with `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`, and programmatically. `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` can be used for a *no hassle* way of implementing iAds in your application. This will create an `ADBannerView` for you and show/hide the `ADBannerView` depending on whether it receives an ad or not from the iAd network.

`self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` is also the reason for your `UILabel` being pushed upwards as you've described and shown in your third image. When your application first launches, whichever `ADBannerView` received an ad from the iAd network first is being favored. That is why sometimes your application looks like your second image, and sometimes your application looks like your third image.

You have two options here, either remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` from your application, which I would personally suggest, or, remove the `ADBannerView` you've created programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Only use the `canDisplayBannerAds` attribute. No need to do anything in storyboard or with callbacks. The ad moves in maintaining your autolayout constraints as defined.
I went crazy with this, finding only complicated attempts. Watched this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-503/ and tried it. It's really that easy.

Comment: This drove me crazy as well. IMO the docs for the canDisplayBannerAds property under the iAdAdditions category on UIViewController definitely does not give the impression that by setting this flag to true the iAd banner is going to be created for you and placed automatically somewhere in the view.